# php if elseif wildcards based on URLs

Tags: php, url, if-statement, canonical-link

Searched high and low for an easier way to do what I do...

I have a function that produces `$absLink` result as `'www.example.com/current/page/'`

I then use this for php if and elseif to do things like:

```
<?php else if ($absLink == 'www.example.com/homepage/' { ?>
This the homepage
<?php } elseif ($absLink == 'www.example.com/about/' { ?>
This the about page
<?php } else { ?>
This probably the 404 not found page
<?php } ?>
```

But sometimes URLs get really deep and I'd like to include similar css styles for multiple pages. Let's say `/about/` also has `/about/staff` and `about/mission-statement/` and in the future more pages will be added... Can I do a wild card? In my mind it would work like this:

```
<?php if ($absLink == 'www.ohiowebgroup.com/about/*') { ?>
Everything in the about directory follows suit to everything here
<?php } else { ?>
Rejection happens here lol
<?php } ?>
```

Make sense? p.s. `$absLink` stands for Absolute Link, although I removed `http://` from it recently cause that's just a non-useful annoyance I decided.

Comment: try to use strpos function, check if substring is present in string

Answer (score 1):

You can see if the variables contains the url using `strpos`.

```
if (strpos($absLink,'www.ohiowebgroup.com/about/')>=0)
```

So here,
if $absLink contains **www.ohiowebgroup.com/about/**, it will returns its position which will be zero if found in the beginning or a positive number based on where it is found. Now this condition will be true irrespective of what comes after `about/`, so it works good for your problem.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Wow, yes that worked! Thank you! Brilliant! I'm hitting your up arrow now

Comment: Ah crap it's creating all kinds of problems now. I'm trying to get to the bottom of it so I can give a good explanation